# Python Matplotlib how to get table only

Tags: python, matplotlib

I modified the [example code](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/table_demo.html) and got the table to work the way I want, however, there's still a box where the graph would go below the table. I want to get rid of that box. Note that the table has 5 rows including column lables and 8 columns including row lables.

The relevant code:

```
columns = ('Last', 'High', 'Low', 'Chg.', 'Chg. %', 'Time', 'T?')
rows = ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Copper', 'Aluminum']
scatter_x = (1, 2, 3)
scatter_y = (1224.53, 1231.76, 1228.70)
fig = plt.figure(1)
gridspec.GridSpec(4,3)

#Table - Main table
plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (0,0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
plt.table(cellText=data_list,
          rowLabels=rows,
          colLabels=columns,
          loc='top')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2,top=0.8)
plt.yticks([])
plt.xticks([])

#Gold Scatter - Small scatter to the right
plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (0,2))
plt.scatter(scatter_x, scatter_y)
plt.ylabel('Gold Last')


fig.tight_layout()
fig.set_size_inches(w=6, h=5)
fig_name = 'plot.png'
fig.savefig(fig_name)
plt.show()
```

And it produces this:
[image: See the empty square below the table]

A tack on question: how would I set the padding on the table so it's not cut off at the top and left?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The table can be added at different positions in- or outside the axes. This is determined by the `loc` argument. In this case it seems you do not want to have the table outside the axes, but inside it. Therefore do not use any of `"top"`, `"bottom"`, `"left"`, `"right"`, but instead e.g.  `loc="upper center"`.

You can then hide the axes it self, via `ax.axis("off")`. In order not to have the row headers be cropped by the figure margin, you may decide not to use `tight layout`.

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

columns = ('Last', 'High', 'Low', 'Chg.', 'Chg. %', 'Time', 'T?')
rows = ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Copper', 'Aluminum']

data_list = np.random.randint(10,90, size=(len(rows), len(columns)))
scatter_x = (1, 2, 3)
scatter_y = (1224.53, 1231.76, 1228.70)

fig = plt.figure(1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.2,top=0.8, wspace=1)

#Table - Main table
ax = plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (0,0), colspan=2, rowspan=2)
ax.table(cellText=data_list,
          rowLabels=rows,
          colLabels=columns, loc="upper center")

ax.axis("off")

#Gold Scatter - Small scatter to the right
plt.subplot2grid((4,3), (0,2))
plt.scatter(scatter_x, scatter_y)
plt.ylabel('Gold Last')

fig.set_size_inches(w=6, h=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]