# output table to left of horizontal bar chart with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to get an output from a dataframe that shows a stacked horizontal bar chart with a table to the left of it.  The relevant data is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cols = ['metric','target','daily_avg','days_green','days_yellow','days_red']
vals = ['Volume',338.65,106.81,63,2,1]

OutDict = dict(zip(cols,vals))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
df = df.append(OutDict, ignore_index = True)
```

I'd like to get something similar to what's in the following: [Python Matplotlib how to get table only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990738/python-matplotlib-how-to-get-table-only#).  I can get the stacked bar chart:

```
df[['days_green','days_yellow','days_red']].plot.barh(stacked=True)
```

Adding in the keyword argument `table=True` puts a table below the chart.  How do I get the axis to either display the df as a table or add one in next to the chart.  Also, the DataFrame will eventually have more than one row, but if I can get it work for one then I should be able to get it to work for n rows.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately using the [`pandas.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method you won't be able to do this. The docs for the `table` parameter state:

> If True, draw a table using the data in the DataFrame and the data will be transposed to meet matplotlib’s default layout. If a Series or DataFrame is passed, use passed data to draw a table.

So you will have to use matplotlib directly to get this done. One option is to create 2 subplots; one for your table and one for your chart. Then you can add the table and modify it as you see fit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

cols = ['metric','target','daily_avg','days_green','days_yellow','days_red']
vals = ['Volume',338.65,106.81,63,2,1]

OutDict = dict(zip(cols,vals))
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)
df = df.append(OutDict, ignore_index = True)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
df[['days_green','days_yellow','days_red']].plot.barh(stacked=True, ax=ax2)
ax1.table(cellText=df[['days_green','days_yellow','days_red']].values, colLabels=['days_green', 'days_yellow', 'days_red'], loc='center')
ax1.axis('off')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, that seems to work, now I just need to get ax2 to be the same size as ax1.  Is there a way to get the chart to be embedded in the dataframe as an extra column?

Comment: That may be worth another question as I'm sure there are others with more experience with that than myself, but I will point out that there is the ability to include bar charts in your dataframe style with [`Pandas DataFrame Styling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Bar-charts)